# The Origins of $Re \lbrace x \rbrace$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I am just starting to take a differentential equations course. We do not use the notation $Re \lbrace x \rbrace$ to describe the real part of a complex number, but I have come accross it in other reading. I am a mathematics major and I was wondering what the proper notation and meaning of $Re \lbrace x \rbrace$ is.

I see it written as $Re(x)$, or $Re \lbrace x \rbrace$. I am wondering if it is a set operation, or a function, or what it is?  If it is a set operation, could we write $Re \lbrace \mathbb{C} \rbrace=\mathbb{R}$? Also, is it common to see such a thing in mathematics courses, or is it a "physics thing"?

Also, could we use $Re \lbrace x \rbrace$ for any $x$ in a field which contains $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Sure you can think of it as projection onto the first coordinate thinking of $\Bbb C$ as $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: $\text{Re}(x)$, sometimes denoted $\Re x$ is indeed a function from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb R$, sister of $\text{Im}(x)=\Im x$. It might make sense to generalize it to other fields, provided a "real part", as opposed to "imaginary" or "non-real", has a meaning there.

Comment: "the real part of an imaginary number": you'd better say a "complex number", as imaginary numbers are understood as those without a real part !

Comment: @YvesDaoust edit has been made.

Comment: It also makes sense to use it in the frame of quaternions, a generalization of the complex numbers, in competition with a "Scalar" function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Scalar_and_vector_parts

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen $\mathrm{Re}\{x\}$ but $\mathrm{Re}(x)$ or $\frak{Re}$$(x)$. It's a function but you can see it as a set operation if there is no ambiguity, though I don't remember having used this for sets.